# Not able to trigger events on the active webpage using content scripts in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to trigger a click event on the active webpage through the Chrome Extension's content script. Though the code is getting injected into web page and alert statements from code is giving me results, the click event is not able to trigger the existing listener event and I am not able to get the desired effect.

Following is my content script code that I am injecting:

```
var script = "var x = document.getElementsByClassName('map-ui');\
              var listOfSuperBlocks = x[0].getElementsByClassName('superblock');\
              alert('Alert gets triggered in the main page');\
              console.log('This gets printed');\
              var eventReturn = listOfSuperBlocks[6].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));\
              console.log('No click event gets triggerd in main page. Value of eventReturn is true');\
              alert('This alert also gets triggerd');";

var scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
scriptElement.innerHTML = script;

document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

As mentioned, alert and console messages are getting printed as expected. But the click event is not triggered and eventReturn value is true.

Is this because of some event propagation is getting blocked?

Comment: Try `dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles:true}))`

Comment: @w0xx0m, I have tried this. But seems like even that is not working. Any chance that the way, click even handler is written in the main page, prevents anyone else from triggering it??

Comment: Select the element in devtools and switch to "Event listeners" sub-panel, then find which element has the event you want.

Answer (score 0):

> function triggerEvent(el, type){
> var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
> e.initEvent(type, false, true);
>
> el.dispatchEvent(e);
> }

```
triggerEvent(listOfSuperBlocks[6],"mousedown")
```